# "git push" hangs indefinitely (for github.com)

Tags: git, github, push

Since yesterday's github outage I haven't been able to `git push` except on rare circumstances if I try it frequently enough.

If I run `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git push` to see more verbose details I get this:

```
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/me/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/me/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
```

I have also tried

```
killall ssh-agent; eval `ssh-agent`
```

but that's not doing anything

I'm on MacOS

Comment: Are you running this on a VPN? Are there multiple hosts configured?

Comment: There's no VPN. How do I check if there's multiple hosts configured? I'm on macOS btw. Thanks

Comment: Just give GitHub time to recover. After short outages, give systems a day; after long outages, give systems a week. (This isn't based on anything other than long experience with system outages and recoveries.)

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the network route is opened/available from your workstation.
(context: [Incident on 2022-09-07 15:04 UTC](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/pz0bvrjx9ztp))

```bash
C:\Users\vonc\git\gitcpl>curl -v telnet://github.com:22
*   Trying 140.82.121.4:22...
* Connected to github.com (140.82.121.4) port 22 (#0)
SSH-2.0-babeld-4047ed67
```

> How do I check if there's multiple hosts configured?

Check the content of `/Users/me/.ssh/config`

> I have also tried
>
> ```
> killall ssh-agent; eval `ssh-agent`
> ```

This applies only for [encrypted private SSH keys](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/129727), and would require you to [`ssh-add` it back](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent).

Comment: Only one host configured.

I've run `curl -v telnet://github.com:22` and it says connected, but then hangs and doesn't print anything like `SSH-2.0-babeld-4047ed67`

Comment: @Zotoaster As long as it says "Connected", that means you can at least contact github through SSH. What is the content of your `~/.ssh/config` file?

Comment: Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile /Users/alastairzotos/.ssh/id_ed25519

Comment: @Zotoaster Can you try with a new SSH key, created without passphrase? (meaning unencrypted, so without having to deal with ssh-agent)